# Electric brewing in UK or Ireland

Tags: boil-kettle, electric

I currently brew beer in my kitchen, but the mess, smells and dirty looks from my wife have taken some of the joy out of my brew day. I started looking into an electric brewing solution that would allow me to move to my garden shed and I need a little advice.

I'm more than happy to drill holes in pots etc. but messing around with mains electricity is a little out of my comfort zone, so I'm looking for a solution that is pretty much ready to go. There are a myriad of options for electric brewing in the US, but these packages are useless for Ireland because of voltage issues.

Ideally, I would like to have an element or series of elements, that can be controlled (e.g. Turned up and down ) and can be plugged into mains electricity (220 volt) and can bring about 20 litres of water to a boil in a reasonable time. This could be a stand alone solution (Burco boiler) or added to my existing stainless steel brew pot.

Does anyone have any experience of a set up like this for the UK or Ireland?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can buy off the shelf equipment that can do all of this. I have two plastic boilers that I got from the local homebrew shop, both have thermistors on the back to control the boil. A friend has got a fancier non-plastic electric boiler/mash tun, which he got from the same place. Have a look at [The Malt Miller's](http://www.themaltmiller.co.uk/index.php?_a=viewCat&catId=16) equipment page, there is everything on there that you need, bar the element. Although I have the feeling that 
something like the [ELECTRIM 5 Gallon BOILER](https://www.hopandgrape.co.uk/electrim-5-gallon-boiler.html) from [Hop & Grape](http://www.hopandgrape.co.uk/) is what you are after.

Comment: Cheers! The Electrim Boiler is exactly what I was looking for.